# Including tag-wiki and tag-wiki guidelines in FAQ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-wiki

I suggest that tag-wikis and guidelines for writing great tag wikis should be included in the FAQ for all the users to see.I am aware that the link to [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) is provided on the *edit-tag-wiki* page.

I feel that creating/editing tag-wikis are one of the most ignored features especially on sec.SE. It will be a great way to let new users know the importance and purpose of tag-wikis and that they can be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the FAQ is for the most important things. Tag wikis are relatively obscure -- asking and answering is what is important (and common) and that's what the faq deals with. The faq is for new users; and new users probably shouldn't be dealing with the tag wikis.

If you wish, you may write up a [faq-proposed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) page on [the mother meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) with hope that it will become a [full faq entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq). Alternatively, suggest an edit to the [privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) and list tag wiki guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel that creating/editing tag-wikis are one of the most ignored
>   features especially on Sec.SE.

I disagree. The current situation is just fine. We discuss tags here on Meta.Sec.SE and The DMZ. We're a relatively small site (less than 9k questions), and that process is sufficient.

The system is working fine; Until you reach 20k rep you cannot edit wiki tags without the community's approval, that's enough to keep the tags neat and clean.